# How to configure Entity class for MySQL database table witch has n:m relationship and multiple primary keys

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

When I run the spring boot project I get the following error 
" Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:"

I have a few other classes with multiple primary keys and foreign keys but they didn't run to an error.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="roles_has_features")
public class RoleFeatures {


    @Column(name = "role_id_fk")
    private Long roleIdFk;


    @Column(name = "feature_id_fk")
    private Long featureIdFk;



    public Long getRoleIdFk() { return roleIdFk; }

    public void setRoleIdFk(Long roleIdFk) { this.roleIdFk = roleIdFk; }

    public Long getFeatureIdFk() { return featureIdFk; }

    public void setFeatureIdFk(Long featureIdFk) { this.featureIdFk = featureIdFk; }


}
```

Comment: The error message is spot on. Your entity does *not* have a primary key. There should be a `@Id` or a `@EmbeddedId` annotation somewhere.

Comment: both "role_id_fk" and "feature_id_fk" are primary keys and foreign keys in the database. So if I add  @Id annotation for both fields, it runs to an error. So do I need to add the extra field as id to the table?

Comment: You cannot, by definition, have more than one primary key. You *can* have a *composite* primary key (a combination of multiple columns that is unique). If this is a join table, (1) you should model it as a `@ManyToMany` and (2) otherwise, you can use an `@EmbeddedId` to represent the composite.

Comment: @SankaHarshana there's a lot going on here. My suggestion is that you get familiar with `javax.persistence` basics first. In the example here you can add a composite id that consists of both (unique) FK, as @chrylis said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with Spring. This is an error thrown by Hibernate, because JPA specification requires an Identity for each entity. As for your case, I would not suggest to create a separate entity, because as far as I understand from your column names, it's just a mapping for a relation between role and feature tables. I'd suggest to JPA Many-To-Many relationship. Take a look at `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable` annotations.

Also this looks as a really good tutorial for me

[Hibernate – Many-to-Many example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

Answer (score 1):

The error message describes the issue pretty well:

> No identifier specified for entity

You do not have an `@Id` annotated column in your `RoleFeatures` entity. Thus, hibernate is unable to identify an entity in the database and refuses to start.

Your so-called entity looks more like an Many-To-Many relationship. Maybe it's better to go this way.

Something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "role_id")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "roles_has_features",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "feature_id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
  private List<Feature> features;

...

}
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: I got it, Thank you very much

Comment: @SankaHarshana Please accept the answer if this does the trick for you :)